# R - how to count values over columns and divide by integers present

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame in which groups vary in sizes, but I want to sum over the rows and divide by *n* (number of integers present), in a new column (**V1.mean**)

It is required that we select column numbers (in this case [10:18]), unless there is a way to do it by name. If so, by all means teach me because I have to transform 8 questions (x9) like this (see example below).

So I tried this:

```
df$v1.mean <- rowSums(cbind(df[10:18]), na.rm = T ) / # sums it up
              ncol(is.integer(cbind(df[10:18] )))     # sums integers, but no
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628332/r-count-numbers-of-certain-values-in-each-column) dplyr example, but I am not sure how to make it work in tally()

Data frame looks like this, with **V1.mean** being the solution I am looking for.

```
  V1.1 V1.2 V1.3 V1.4 V1.5 V1.6 V1.7 V1.8  V1.9 V2.1 | V1.mean V2.mean
1     5    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   5  | 4.67 [== (5+4+5)/3]
2     5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   3
3     5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  ...
4     5    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  ...
5     5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  ...
6     5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  ...
7     5    5    5    4    4   NA   NA   NA   NA  ...
8     5    5    5    4    5    5   NA   NA   NA  ... | 4.83 [== (5+5+5+4+5+5)/6]
9     4    5    5    5    4   NA   NA   NA   NA  ...
10    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  ...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried `rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: `rowMeans(df[grep('V1',names(df)], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to `split` the data into a `list` of `data.frame`s and ge the `rowMeans`

```
nm1 <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(df1))
df1[paste0(unique(nm1), ".mean")] <- sapply(split.default(df1,
       sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(df1))), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)

df1
#   V1.1 V1.2 V1.3 V1.4 V1.5 V1.6 V1.7 V1.8 V1.9 V2.1  V1.mean V2.mean
#1     5    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    5 4.666667       5
#2     5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    3 5.000000       3
#3     5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    4 5.000000       4
#4     5    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    3 4.666667       3
#5     5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    2 5.000000       2
#6     5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1 5.000000       1
#7     5    5    5    4    4   NA   NA   NA   NA    5 4.600000       5
#8     5    5    5    4    5    5   NA   NA   NA    4 4.833333       4
#9     4    5    5    5    4   NA   NA   NA   NA    1 4.600000       1
#10    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    5 5.000000       5
```

---

Or using the same logic in a tidyverse chain

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   split.default(nm1) %>%
   map_dfc(rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   rename_all(~ str_c(., ".mean")) %>% 
   bind_cols(df1, .)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1.1 = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L
), V1.2 = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), V1.3 = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), V1.4 = c(NA, NA, 5L, NA, 
NA, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA), V1.5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 
5L, 4L, NA), V1.6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA), 
    V1.7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V1.8 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V1.9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2.1 = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Your base code gave a correct result, however your `tidyverse` example returned this `Error in df1 %>% split.default(nm1) %>% map_dfc(rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE) %>%  :   could not find function "%>%"`

Comment: @fleems  Have you loaded `dplyr` i.e. `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Yea works, I had the `plyr` package running from @Wave's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Akrun gave the correct answer, but for most analyses your data is not in the easiest format.

You might want to consider melting the data.

```
x = melt(as.matrix(df),varnames = c('row','col'))
x$id = substr(x$col,1,2)
ddply(x,c('row','id'),summarise,mean=mean(value,na.rm = T)) # or aggregate, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I usually subset and merge if I want to calculate a mean when the data is like this. It reduces the complexity of a given line of code, since I have to share the script. I prefer to stay in a data.frame instead of converting it to a matrix, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think a much simpler solution is `row_mean` from `hablar`. I reuse the df from @akrun.

```
library(hablar)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(v1.mean = row_mean_(contains("v1")))
```

which gives you:

```
   V1.1 V1.2 V1.3 V1.4 V1.5 V1.6 V1.7 V1.8 V1.9 V2.1  v1.mean
1     5    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    5 4.666667
2     5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    3 5.000000
3     5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    4 5.000000
4     5    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    3 4.666667
5     5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    2 5.000000
6     5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1 5.000000
7     5    5    5    4    4   NA   NA   NA   NA    5 4.600000
8     5    5    5    4    5    5   NA   NA   NA    4 4.833333
9     4    5    5    5    4   NA   NA   NA   NA    1 4.600000
10    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    5 5.000000
```

Comment: Wow, that's clean. Thanks for the comment!